# Virtual Box not opening

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I was using VirtualBox normally the other day, when I turned off my Mac and turned it on I keep getting the error, I even tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it and still getting the error, any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as the error message states: `VirtualBox.xml` is empty. This file contains the configuration of VirtualBox, including the VM library.

There may be a `VirtualBox.xml-prev` file next to it. You can try renaming this file to `VirtualBox.xml` and see if that helps. If it doesn’t, just remove the file. The file contents are already gone. VirtualBox will recreate it, but you need to add all virtual machines manually.

If you have Time Machine (or another backup solution) enabled, you may be able to restore an undamaged version of the file.

The `Library` folder is hidden by default. You can open it by using the “Go to folder” function in Finder (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). Just paste the following path:

```
/Users/Dory/Library/VirtualBox
```

Alternatively, using Terminal is also an option if you’re familiar with Linux/UNIX command line.